# Does this multi-line form interface pattern have a name?

Tags: gui-design, design-patterns

I've got a form where the user needs to enter a number of records (varies for each screen), and the UI approach I'm considering is to have multiple rows, with the ability to add and remove rows, something akin to:

```
    -------- -------- X
    -------- -------- X
 +  -------- -------- X
```

Where clicking + adds another row, and clicking X removes a particular row. I'm interested to know of there are any names for this pattern so I can find appropriate documentation for the app framework we're using to develop it (it's a somewhat clunky RAD framework - so we've got a bit of work to do to make it do what we need).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pattern for adding/removing an item within a form](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/50795/pattern-for-adding-removing-an-item-within-a-form)

Comment: @Nash The proposed duplicate does not answer OP's question. OP is asking *if this particular pattern has a name*, and if so, what it is.

Comment: @Adam, I'm not sure of a specific name for it (not to say it doesn't have one), but to help extend your search, I've seen a lot of To-Do and other productivity apps that allow rapid item creation by using a quick-add pattern like this.

Comment: I have seen it referred to as a Form Stack.

Comment: You seem to know the functionality, so why you worry about the implementation? In my opinion, this question is off-topic. Why adding a row, delete a row or inline-editing should have another name just because are in a table?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a widely or generally used term but in the world of Wordpress custom fields, this kind of pattern is referred to as a "repeater". A repeater can be a repeating text field, a repeating image input, repeating anything. So in your case it would just be referred to as a "repeater text field".

Hope that helps! Here's a link to a popular Wordpress plugin that allows for the easy creation of custom repeater fields. There's a video there that might help illustrate how the ui pattern looks: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/repeater/

Also in searching the web for "repeater ui" pattern I found a bunch of websites using the term for similar things so I think that this is probably one of the more popular options.